# How do I pass a function to a child component using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In version 0.13.x version of react-router, functions could be passed to child components of the RouteHandler as a prop by doing something like:

```
<RouteHandler foo={this.foo} {...this.state} />
```

I have recently upgraded to version 1.0.0 and found that the new syntax does not let me attach functions:

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...this.state}, foo={this.foo})}
```

The code above throws a compilation error as `foo={this.foo}` is an unexpected token (I am aware that foo={this.foo} does not belong here, but where do I put it now?).

How do I attach functions to the component so that I can invoke them from child components? My use case here is that I want my child components to be able to invoke an emit event which will tell the server to push a notification to connected sockets, which will synchronise with connected clients.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `React.cloneElement` ([docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/clone-with-props.html)) is as follows:

```
React.cloneElement(element: ReactElement|ReactElement[], props: object)
```

As a result, your call isn't going to work - never mind the fact it is invalid syntax. What you're looking for is something a bit like this:

```
React.cloneElement(this.props.children, merge(this.state, this.foo))
```

Where `merge` is a function that can combine N many objects together (hopefully you realise you may end up with clobbering). For extra points, you may want to use an immutable merge. If you're using [immutable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutable) (you are, right?), you **could** do that like this:

```
import {Map} from 'immutable'

const newProps = Map(this.state).merge(Map({ foo: this.foo }))
return React.cloneElement(this.props.children, newProps)
```

That might be a bit overkill for you, though.